# Disable next month in datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to disable next 30 days in datepicker. For ex. It is 27th March today so the user will be able to select anything after 27th April.
This I have tried so far-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div class="demo">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script> 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
<script>
 var today = new Date();
 var D = today.getDate();
 var M = today.getMonth()+2;
 var Y = today.getFullYear();
    $( '#datepicker' ).datepicker({ 
     format: "dd mm yyyy",
          autoclose: true,
        startDate: new Date(D,M,Y),
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Unfortunately I am not able to achieve the desired result. However there is no error message in the console.

Comment: so only from 27th April as per your example , the user should be able to select the dates not any day before 27th April?

Comment: yes, the user should not be able to select any date before 27th April.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code.

```
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ minDate: "+1M" });
  } );
```

I have not tried this but according to their [doc](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#min-max) it should work.

### Update

`+1M` will add exact one month not days.

Comment: Well I know that. You can accept the answer which helped you the most. :) @J.Doe

Comment: if you wanted to add a month, this will be the correct answer imo. other answers add 30 days

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @AbdulHameed I will update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
minDate: "+30d",
```

before the autoclose

or

```
$('#datepicker')({
    minDate: "+30d"
});
```

Also you can use "+1M" instead of "+30d" to add 1 entire month.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    minDate: "+30d"
});
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nh6eoj03/1010/)

**Explanation:** `minDate` is used to set the date from which datepicker starts.

Answer (score 0):

```
/*there is problem in parsing the date you can use the following format 
the calender will start from the next months date from new date
*/   
 var today = new Date();
     var D = today.getDate()+1;
     var M = today.getMonth()+1;
     var Y = today.getFullYear();
    var date = new Date(Y,M,D);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one example for datepicker, to select 30days

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
   format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
   startDate: new Date(),
   endDate: "+30d"
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use this code:

```
var max = new Date('April 26, 2018');
$('#datepicker').datepicker('option', 'maxDate', max);
```

Comment: this is not what the OP wanted. this code disables all dates after 26 April 2018 not nefore

Comment: You can use:

    $( '#datepicker' ).datepicker({ 
  format: "dd mm yyyy",
  autoclose: true,
  startDate: new Date(D,M,Y),
  beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends
    });

In that example, calendar will disable weekends.
You should  define a function with your desire range.